# how to tell if ms access file was created as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: ms-access

I inherited a 2013 ms access db file but i do not know if the user created it with a 32- or 64-bit version of access.  I know how to check my system settings to see what type my OS and MSO are, but how do I tell how a specific third-party file was created?

Comment: There is no such info as the file format is not an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting [article](https://www.devhut.net/2017/04/13/access-x32-vs-x64-compatibility/) about it.

> ### The General Rule
>
> As a general rule, a database (in accdb file format) developed on Access x32 should run fine on Access x64 and vice versa.
>
> ### When the General Rule Goes Awry
>
> Although, a database made on Access x32 should run fine on Access x64 (and vice versa), some people report issues. You have 2 options:
>
> - Create a new blank database in the target bitness and import everything
> - Decompile the original database and migrate it to the other bitness and then recompile it

The article also quotes the Microsoft:

> “We recommend the 32-bit version of Office for most users, because it’s more compatible with most other applications, especially third-party add-ins.” — Microsoft, see: [64-bit editions of Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx#BKMK_Scenarios)

If you run into the above problem, you can choose a preferred bitness (e.g. 32 bit) and for [users with 64-bit Access (see the VBA code)](http://officeoneonline.com/vba/bitness.html) display a warning.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it doesn't matter. I'm pretty sure that they use the same file format.

Answer (score 1):

If you talking about a accDB, then the creating version x32 or x64 should not matter.

However if you using a compiled accDE, then the x64 bit version of Access can ONLY open a x64 bit accDE file, and the same applies to a x32 accDE (they can only be opened with Access x32).

I don’t believe there is a “easy” way to determine if the file was created with x32 or x64 bit Access.